# Decode an animated image using libwebp DLLs and JNA

Tags: java, jna, webp, animated-webp

I need to read static and animated WebP images in Java. There is no DLL offered for [libwepb](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download), so I've downloaded the [source](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.2.2.tar.gz) and compiled it in the Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 on Windows like this:

```
..\libwebp-1.2.2>nmake /f Makefile.vc CFG=release-dynamic RTLIBCFG=dynamic OBJDIR=output
```

This resulted in the files `libwebp.dll`, `libwebpdecoder.dll` and `libwebpdemux.dll`. I'm using `jna-5.12.1.jar` for JNA. I was able to decode a static image using the `libwebp.dll` and the function `WebPDecodeRGBA`, however decoding an animated image doesn't work with that. From what I understand the demux functions in `libwebpdemux.dll` are required for that.

I tried to implement the [WebPAnimDecoder](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/demux.h#L221) API, but I'm already stuck at creating the decoder:

```c
WebPAnimDecoder* dec = WebPAnimDecoderNew(webp_data, &dec_options);
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/demux.h#L281) it looks like `dec_options` can just be null to get a default, but I'm not sure how it wants the `webp_data`. I tried to implement the [WebPData struct](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/mux_types.h#L59), but I'm not sure if that is even correct.

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "bytes", "length" })
public static class WebPData extends Structure {
    public byte[] bytes;
    public int length;
}
```

I've gotten an "Invalid memory access" exception by just assigning the bytes directly `data.bytes = rawdata;`. At the WebP struct definition it says "'bytes' memory must be allocated using [WebPMalloc()](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/types.h#L59) and such.", so I assume that is required somehow, but I don't know how that would work, how do I get the data in there? The way it is now throws an exception complaining about the return type.

What also confuses me is that the [example](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/demux.h#L230) calls [`WebPAnimDecoderNew`](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/demux.h#L287), but that function is not exported, so I can't access it. Instead, there is a function called [`WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal`](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/v1.2.2/src/webp/demux.h#L274) with an additional int parameter that apparently is supposed to receive the `WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION` constant. I'm not quite sure what the signficance of that is. Am I really supposed to call the "Internal" function?

This is what I've been testing with (more information in some comments):

```java
package webptest;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.awt.image.DirectColorModel;
import java.awt.image.SampleModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WebPDecodingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "<path>\\lib\\x64");
        
        // This only shows the first image
        ImageIcon staticImage = decodeStatic("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.webp");
        ImageIcon animatedImage = decodeStatic("https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/webp/images/dancing_banana2.lossless.webp");
        showImages(staticImage, animatedImage);
        
        // This throws an error (and it's incomplete anyway)
        ImageIcon[] animatedImage2 = decodeAnimated("https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/webp/images/dancing_banana2.lossless.webp");
        showImages(animatedImage2);
    }

    //==========================
    // Animated image
    //==========================
    
    /**
     * Decode the frames of an animated image. Doesn't work and incomplete.
     */
    private static ImageIcon[] decodeAnimated(String url) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawData = getBytesFromURL(new URL(url));
        System.out.println("Bytes length: "+rawData.length);

        /**
         * I assume that this is already not correct. In a C example
         * (examples/anim_util.c) it uses "WebPDataInit(&webp_data);" first, but
         * that function isn't exported. It's in "src/webp/mux_types.h":
         * 
             // Initializes the contents of the 'webp_data' object with default values.
            static WEBP_INLINE void WebPDataInit(WebPData* webp_data) {
              if (webp_data != NULL) {
                memset(webp_data, 0, sizeof(*webp_data));
              }
            }
         * 
         * I tried just assigning the data direclty like "data.bytes = rawdata;"
         * however that resulted in a "Invalid memory access" exception when
         * calling "WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal".
         * 
         * At the definition of the WebPData struct (see above) it says
         * "'bytes' memory must be allocated using WebPMalloc() and such."
         * so I assume that might be required to be used, but I'm not sure how.
         * 
         * The way it is now throws a "Unsupported return type class [B in
         * function WebPMalloc" exception.
         */
        LibWebPDemux.WebPData data = new LibWebPDemux.WebPData();
        data.bytes = LibWebP.INSTANCE.WebPMalloc(rawData.length);
        data.length = rawData.length;

        // This may not be required, instead "null" can be provided for default options
//        LibWebPDemux.WebPAnimDecoderOptions options = new LibWebPDemux.WebPAnimDecoderOptions();
//        int initResult = LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderOptionsInitInternal(options, LibWebPDemux.WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION);
//        System.out.println(initResult);

        Pointer dec = LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(data, null, LibWebPDemux.WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION);
        System.out.println(dec);
        
        // Just testing if accessing the lib works at all (it appears to)
//        int version = LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPGetDemuxVersion();
//        System.out.println(version);
        return null;
    }
    
    //==========================
    // libwebp
    //==========================
    public interface LibWebP extends Library {

        LibWebP INSTANCE = Native.load("libwebp", LibWebP.class);

        /*
        [webp/decode.h]
            // Retrieve basic header information: width, height.
            // This function will also validate the header, returning true on success,
            // false otherwise. '*width' and '*height' are only valid on successful return.
            // Pointers 'width' and 'height' can be passed NULL if deemed irrelevant.
            // Note: The following chunk sequences (before the raw VP8/VP8L data) are
            // considered valid by this function:
            // RIFF + VP8(L)
            // RIFF + VP8X + (optional chunks) + VP8(L)
            // ALPH + VP8 <-- Not a valid WebP format: only allowed for internal purpose.
            // VP8(L)     <-- Not a valid WebP format: only allowed for internal purpose.
            WEBP_EXTERN int WebPGetInfo(const uint8_t* data, size_t data_size,
                                        int* width, int* height);
        */
        public int WebPGetInfo(byte[] data, int data_size, IntByReference width, IntByReference height);
        
        /*
        [webp/decode.h]
            // Decodes WebP images pointed to by 'data' and returns RGBA samples, along
            // with the dimensions in *width and *height. The ordering of samples in
            // memory is R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A... in scan order (endian-independent).
            // The returned pointer should be deleted calling WebPFree().
            // Returns NULL in case of error.
            WEBP_EXTERN uint8_t* WebPDecodeRGBA(const uint8_t* data, size_t data_size,
                                                int* width, int* height);
        */
        public Pointer WebPDecodeRGBA(byte[] data, int data_size, IntByReference width, IntByReference height);
        
        /*
        [webp/types.h]
            // Allocates 'size' bytes of memory. Returns NULL upon error. Memory
            // must be deallocated by calling WebPFree(). This function is made available
            // by the core 'libwebp' library.
            WEBP_EXTERN void* WebPMalloc(size_t size);
        */
        public byte[] WebPMalloc(int size);
        
        /*
        [webp/types.h]
            // Releases memory returned by the WebPDecode*() functions (from decode.h).
            WEBP_EXTERN void WebPFree(void* ptr);
        */
        public void WebPFree(Pointer pointer);
    }
    
    //==========================
    // libwebpdemux
    //==========================
    public interface LibWebPDemux extends Library {
        LibWebPDemux INSTANCE = Native.load("libwebpdemux", LibWebPDemux.class);
        
        static final int WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION = 0x0107;
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Internal, version-checked, entry point.
            WEBP_EXTERN WebPAnimDecoder* WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(
                const WebPData*, const WebPAnimDecoderOptions*, int);

            // Creates and initializes a WebPAnimDecoder object.
            // Parameters:
            //   webp_data - (in) WebP bitstream. This should remain unchanged during the
            //                    lifetime of the output WebPAnimDecoder object.
            //   dec_options - (in) decoding options. Can be passed NULL to choose
            //                      reasonable defaults (in particular, color mode MODE_RGBA
            //                      will be picked).
            // Returns:
            //   A pointer to the newly created WebPAnimDecoder object, or NULL in case of
            //   parsing error, invalid option or memory error.
            static WEBP_INLINE WebPAnimDecoder* WebPAnimDecoderNew(
                const WebPData* webp_data, const WebPAnimDecoderOptions* dec_options) {
              return WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(webp_data, dec_options,
                                                WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION);
            }
        */
        public Pointer WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(WebPData webp_data, Structure dec_options, int version);
        
        /*
        [webp/mux_types.h]
            // Data type used to describe 'raw' data, e.g., chunk data
            // (ICC profile, metadata) and WebP compressed image data.
            // 'bytes' memory must be allocated using WebPMalloc() and such.
            struct WebPData {
              const uint8_t* bytes;
              size_t size;
            };
        */
        @Structure.FieldOrder({ "bytes", "length" })
        public static class WebPData extends Structure {
            public byte[] bytes;
            public int length;
        }
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Returns the version number of the demux library, packed in hexadecimal using
            // 8bits for each of major/minor/revision. E.g: v2.5.7 is 0x020507.
            WEBP_EXTERN int WebPGetDemuxVersion(void);
        */
        public int WebPGetDemuxVersion();
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Internal, version-checked, entry point.
            WEBP_EXTERN int WebPAnimDecoderOptionsInitInternal(
                WebPAnimDecoderOptions*, int);

            // Should always be called, to initialize a fresh WebPAnimDecoderOptions
            // structure before modification. Returns false in case of version mismatch.
            // WebPAnimDecoderOptionsInit() must have succeeded before using the
            // 'dec_options' object.
            static WEBP_INLINE int WebPAnimDecoderOptionsInit(
                WebPAnimDecoderOptions* dec_options) {
              return WebPAnimDecoderOptionsInitInternal(dec_options,
                                                        WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION);
            }
        */
        public int WebPAnimDecoderOptionsInitInternal(WebPAnimDecoderOptions options, int version);
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Global options.
            struct WebPAnimDecoderOptions {
              // Output colorspace. Only the following modes are supported:
              // MODE_RGBA, MODE_BGRA, MODE_rgbA and MODE_bgrA.
              WEBP_CSP_MODE color_mode;
              int use_threads;           // If true, use multi-threaded decoding.
              uint32_t padding[7];       // Padding for later use.
            };
        
        [webp/decode.h]
            typedef enum WEBP_CSP_MODE {
              MODE_RGB = 0, MODE_RGBA = 1,
              MODE_BGR = 2, MODE_BGRA = 3,
              MODE_ARGB = 4, MODE_RGBA_4444 = 5,
              MODE_RGB_565 = 6,
              // RGB-premultiplied transparent modes (alpha value is preserved)
              MODE_rgbA = 7,
              MODE_bgrA = 8,
              MODE_Argb = 9,
              MODE_rgbA_4444 = 10,
              // YUV modes must come after RGB ones.
              MODE_YUV = 11, MODE_YUVA = 12,  // yuv 4:2:0
              MODE_LAST = 13
            } WEBP_CSP_MODE;
        */
        @Structure.FieldOrder({ "color_mode", "use_threads", "padding" })
        public static class WebPAnimDecoderOptions extends Structure {
            public int color_mode; // enum
            public int use_threads;
            public int[] padding = new int[7];
        }
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Global information about the animation..
            struct WebPAnimInfo {
              uint32_t canvas_width;
              uint32_t canvas_height;
              uint32_t loop_count;
              uint32_t bgcolor;
              uint32_t frame_count;
              uint32_t pad[4];   // padding for later use
            };
        */
        @Structure.FieldOrder({ "canvas_width", "canvas_height", "loop_count", "bgcolor", "frame_count", "pad" })
        public static class WebPAnimInfo extends Structure {
            public int canvas_width;
            public int canvas_height;
            public int loop_count;
            public int bgcolor;
            public int frame_count;
            public int[] pad = new int[4];
        }
    }
    
    //==========================
    // Static image
    //==========================
    
    /**
     * Decoding a static WebP image. I'm not sure if it's entirely correct, but
     * at least an image comes out of it.
     */
    private static ImageIcon decodeStatic(String url) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawData = getBytesFromURL(new URL(url));
        IntByReference widthRef = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference heightRef = new IntByReference();
        int result = LibWebP.INSTANCE.WebPGetInfo(rawData, rawData.length, widthRef, heightRef);
        if (result == 1) {
//            System.out.println(widthRef.getValue() + " " + heightRef.getValue());

            Pointer pixelData = LibWebP.INSTANCE.WebPDecodeRGBA(rawData, rawData.length, widthRef, heightRef);
            if (pixelData != null) {
                int width = widthRef.getValue();
                int height = heightRef.getValue();

                int[] pixels = pixelData.getIntArray(0, width * height);

                ColorModel colorModel;
                colorModel = new DirectColorModel(32, 0x000000ff, 0x0000ff00, 0x00ff0000, 0xff000000);

                SampleModel sampleModel = colorModel.createCompatibleSampleModel(width, height);
                DataBufferInt db = new DataBufferInt(pixels, width * height);
                WritableRaster raster = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, db, null);

                Image img = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, new Hashtable<Object, Object>());
                return new ImageIcon(img);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Not a valid WebP");
        return null;
    }
    
    //==========================
    // General Helpers
    //==========================
    private static void showImages(ImageIcon... icons) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            for (ImageIcon icon : icons) {
                frame.add(new JLabel(icon), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
    
    public static byte[] getBytesFromURL(URL url) throws Exception {
        URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
        try (InputStream input = c.getInputStream()) {
            byte[] imageData = readAllBytes(input);
            return imageData;
        }
    }
    
    private static byte[] readAllBytes(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toByteArray();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JNA structures need their size information to be properly allocated, so this mapping should have given you an error without specifying the byte array size:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "bytes", "length" })
public static class WebPData extends Structure {
    public byte[] bytes;
    public int length;
}
```

Since you've indicated the bytes are allocated elsewhere, the pointer to the array should just be mapped with a `Pointer`. Also the type of `length` is `size_t` so you need to use that mapping for either *nix, or the `SIZE_T` mapping for Windows.

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "bytes", "length" })
public static class WebPData extends Structure {
    public Pointer bytes;
    public BaseTSD.SIZE_T length;
}
```

You could then manually allocate the bytes. You indicate `WebPMalloc()` does that but I don't know how that's any different than just using `malloc()` or equivalent which is under the hood if you use JNA's `new Memory(size)`.  If you use that function you would pass the length value as a parameter to that function and the return value would be a `Pointer` that you would set as `bytes`.

Once you've set the bytes to a pointer to the length-sized allocation, you can pass the structure as the `webp_data` argument.

It is possible that with your mapping of `byte[]` the native code tried to make it work (as that's just a pointer) but using `int` for the length may have not been correct if `size_t` was 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Daniel Widdis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72905282/) I changed the `WebPData`'s `bytes` field to a Pointer again. I didn't really know before how to get my raw data into that, not sure why I didn't notice the Pointer's `write()` method before.

The type of the `WebPData`'s `length` field almost doesn't seem to matter (`short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double` all worked), I guess it automatically converts it somehow. Not sure if that could break under different circumstances/systems though.

Both `new Memory()` and the native `WebPMalloc()` function seem to work for allocating the memory. I've looked at what the function actually does:

```c
void* WebPMalloc(size_t size) {
  return WebPSafeMalloc(1, size);
}

void* WebPSafeMalloc(uint64_t nmemb, size_t size) {
  void* ptr;
  Increment(&num_malloc_calls);
  if (!CheckSizeArgumentsOverflow(nmemb, size)) return NULL;
  assert(nmemb * size > 0);
  ptr = malloc((size_t)(nmemb * size));
  AddMem(ptr, (size_t)(nmemb * size));
  return ptr;
}
```

I don't fully understand what that does, but it seems to be doing some additional checks and management. Not sure if it's necessary to use it, but might as well if the library recommends it?

After providing the data as a Pointer, I got the decoder object. The only thing from there that I had some issues with was the function to get the next frame:

```c
WEBP_EXTERN int WebPAnimDecoderGetNext(WebPAnimDecoder* dec,
                                                   uint8_t** buf, int* timestamp);
```

It seems to be a double pointer? So I had to get the Pointer from the reference, and then the Pointer from that again:

```java
PointerByReference buf = new PointerByReference();
IntByReference timestamp = new IntByReference();
int nextResult = LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderGetNext(dec, buf, timestamp);
ImageIcon icon = createImage(buf.getPointer().getPointer(0), info.canvas_width, info.canvas_height);
```

Here's the updated code, cleaned up a bit to what is actually used. I'm not sure if it's entirely correct, but I'm getting the frames and other info now, so it shouldn't be that wrong at least.

It definitely needs some proper error checking and I'm not sure if I need to clean up any more memory afterwards.

```java
package webptest;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.awt.image.DirectColorModel;
import java.awt.image.SampleModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WebPDecodingTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "<path>\\lib\\x64");
        ImageIcon[] animatedImage = decodeAnimated("https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/webp/images/dancing_banana2.lossless.webp");
        showImages(animatedImage);
    }
    
    //==========================
    // Animated image
    //==========================
    
    /**
     * Decode the frames of an animated image. Doesn't work and incomplete.
     */
    private static ImageIcon[] decodeAnimated(String url) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawData = getBytesFromURL(new URL(url));
        LibWebPDemux.WebPData data = new LibWebPDemux.WebPData();
        data.bytes = LibWebP.INSTANCE.WebPMalloc(rawData.length);
        // This worked as well
//        data.bytes = new Memory(rawData.length);

        data.bytes.write(0, rawData, 0, rawData.length);
        data.length = rawData.length;
        Pointer dec = LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(data, null, LibWebPDemux.WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION);
        System.out.println(dec);
        
        LibWebPDemux.WebPAnimInfo info = new LibWebPDemux.WebPAnimInfo();
        LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderGetInfo(dec, info);
        System.out.println(info.canvas_width+" "+info.canvas_height+" "+info.frame_count);
        ImageIcon[] result = new ImageIcon[info.frame_count];
        int frame = 0;
        while (LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderHasMoreFrames(dec) == 1) {
            PointerByReference buf = new PointerByReference();
            IntByReference timestamp = new IntByReference();
            
            int nextResult = LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderGetNext(dec, buf, timestamp);
            System.out.println(nextResult+" "+timestamp.getValue());
            
            ImageIcon icon = createImage(buf.getPointer().getPointer(0), info.canvas_width, info.canvas_height);
            result[frame] = icon;
            frame++;
        }
        /**
         * Not sure if this is correct or if other stuff needs to be cleared as
         * well.
         */
        LibWebPDemux.INSTANCE.WebPAnimDecoderDelete(dec);
        LibWebP.INSTANCE.WebPFree(data.bytes);
        return result;
    }
    
    //==========================
    // libwebp
    //==========================
    public interface LibWebP extends Library {

        LibWebP INSTANCE = Native.load("libwebp", LibWebP.class);
        
        /*
        [webp/types.h]
            // Allocates 'size' bytes of memory. Returns NULL upon error. Memory
            // must be deallocated by calling WebPFree(). This function is made available
            // by the core 'libwebp' library.
            WEBP_EXTERN void* WebPMalloc(size_t size);
        */
        public Pointer WebPMalloc(int size);
        
        /*
        [webp/types.h]
            // Releases memory returned by the WebPDecode*() functions (from decode.h).
            WEBP_EXTERN void WebPFree(void* ptr);
        */
        public void WebPFree(Pointer pointer);
    }
    
    //==========================
    // libwebpdemux
    //==========================
    public interface LibWebPDemux extends Library {
        LibWebPDemux INSTANCE = Native.load("libwebpdemux", LibWebPDemux.class);
        
        static final int WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION = 0x0107;
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Internal, version-checked, entry point.
            WEBP_EXTERN WebPAnimDecoder* WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(
                const WebPData*, const WebPAnimDecoderOptions*, int);

            // Creates and initializes a WebPAnimDecoder object.
            // Parameters:
            //   webp_data - (in) WebP bitstream. This should remain unchanged during the
            //                    lifetime of the output WebPAnimDecoder object.
            //   dec_options - (in) decoding options. Can be passed NULL to choose
            //                      reasonable defaults (in particular, color mode MODE_RGBA
            //                      will be picked).
            // Returns:
            //   A pointer to the newly created WebPAnimDecoder object, or NULL in case of
            //   parsing error, invalid option or memory error.
            static WEBP_INLINE WebPAnimDecoder* WebPAnimDecoderNew(
                const WebPData* webp_data, const WebPAnimDecoderOptions* dec_options) {
              return WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(webp_data, dec_options,
                                                WEBP_DEMUX_ABI_VERSION);
            }
        */
        public Pointer WebPAnimDecoderNewInternal(WebPData webp_data, Structure dec_options, int version);
        
        /*
        [webp/mux_types.h]
            // Data type used to describe 'raw' data, e.g., chunk data
            // (ICC profile, metadata) and WebP compressed image data.
            // 'bytes' memory must be allocated using WebPMalloc() and such.
            struct WebPData {
              const uint8_t* bytes;
              size_t size;
            };
        */
        @Structure.FieldOrder({ "bytes", "length" })
        public static class WebPData extends Structure {
            public Pointer bytes;
            
            public long length;
        }
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Get global information about the animation.
            // Parameters:
            //   dec - (in) decoder instance to get information from.
            //   info - (out) global information fetched from the animation.
            // Returns:
            //   True on success.
            WEBP_EXTERN int WebPAnimDecoderGetInfo(const WebPAnimDecoder* dec,
                                                   WebPAnimInfo* info);
        */
        public int WebPAnimDecoderGetInfo(Pointer dec, WebPAnimInfo info);
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Global information about the animation..
            struct WebPAnimInfo {
              uint32_t canvas_width;
              uint32_t canvas_height;
              uint32_t loop_count;
              uint32_t bgcolor;
              uint32_t frame_count;
              uint32_t pad[4];   // padding for later use
            };
        */
        @Structure.FieldOrder({ "canvas_width", "canvas_height", "loop_count", "bgcolor", "frame_count", "pad" })
        public static class WebPAnimInfo extends Structure {
            public int canvas_width;
            public int canvas_height;
            public int loop_count;
            public int bgcolor;
            public int frame_count;
            public int[] pad = new int[4];
        }
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Check if there are more frames left to decode.
            // Parameters:
            //   dec - (in) decoder instance to be checked.
            // Returns:
            //   True if 'dec' is not NULL and some frames are yet to be decoded.
            //   Otherwise, returns false.
            WEBP_EXTERN int WebPAnimDecoderHasMoreFrames(const WebPAnimDecoder* dec);
        */
        public int WebPAnimDecoderHasMoreFrames(Pointer dec);
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Fetch the next frame from 'dec' based on options supplied to
            // WebPAnimDecoderNew(). This will be a fully reconstructed canvas of size
            // 'canvas_width * 4 * canvas_height', and not just the frame sub-rectangle. The
            // returned buffer 'buf' is valid only until the next call to
            // WebPAnimDecoderGetNext(), WebPAnimDecoderReset() or WebPAnimDecoderDelete().
            // Parameters:
            //   dec - (in/out) decoder instance from which the next frame is to be fetched.
            //   buf - (out) decoded frame.
            //   timestamp - (out) timestamp of the frame in milliseconds.
            // Returns:
            //   False if any of the arguments are NULL, or if there is a parsing or
            //   decoding error, or if there are no more frames. Otherwise, returns true.
            WEBP_EXTERN int WebPAnimDecoderGetNext(WebPAnimDecoder* dec,
                                                   uint8_t** buf, int* timestamp);
        */
        public int WebPAnimDecoderGetNext(Pointer dec, PointerByReference buf, IntByReference timestamp);
        
        /*
        [webp/demux.h]
            // Deletes the WebPAnimDecoder object.
            // Parameters:
            //   dec - (in/out) decoder instance to be deleted
            WEBP_EXTERN void WebPAnimDecoderDelete(WebPAnimDecoder* dec);
        */
        public void WebPAnimDecoderDelete(Pointer dec);
    }
    
    //==========================
    // General Helpers
    //==========================
    private static ImageIcon createImage(Pointer pixelData, int width, int height) {
        if (pixelData != null) {
            int[] pixels = pixelData.getIntArray(0, width * height);

            ColorModel colorModel;
            colorModel = new DirectColorModel(32, 0x000000ff, 0x0000ff00, 0x00ff0000, 0xff000000);

            SampleModel sampleModel = colorModel.createCompatibleSampleModel(width, height);
            DataBufferInt db = new DataBufferInt(pixels, width * height);
            WritableRaster raster = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, db, null);

            Image img = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, new Hashtable<Object, Object>());
            return new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(100, 100, 0)); // Resized for testing
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private static void showImages(ImageIcon... icons) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            for (ImageIcon icon : icons) {
                frame.add(new JLabel(icon), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
        
    }
    
    public static byte[] getBytesFromURL(URL url) throws Exception {
        URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
        try (InputStream input = c.getInputStream()) {
            byte[] imageData = readAllBytes(input);
            return imageData;
        }
    }
    
    private static byte[] readAllBytes(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toByteArray();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "The type of the WebPData's length field almost doesn't seem to matter" -- in the Structure it probably doesn't due to padding.   As an argument to the allocation function passed on the stack, it absolutely does matter and can lead to intermittent and weird failures.   For the `uint8_t** buf` the `PointerByReference` is right but you probably want `buf.getValue()` rather than `buf.getPointer()`.

Comment: As for the memory allocation, the "checks" are just that "length*size" are above zero and don't overflow. There truly is no difference between using that and `Memory` which also uses `malloc()`. I'd just use `Memory` which will clean itself up afterwards (in JNA 5.12.1 you can use try-with-resources with it!).

Comment: As suspected I ran into an issue with the `length` field being `long`, it broke when I switch to a 32bit JRE/libs. In that case `int` worked fine, but I changed it now so it respects the `Native.SIZE_T_SIZE` instead of guessing what might not break it at some point.